# RoutingError for Rails 3.1 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, omniauth

I keep getting routing errors for things that work fine in other environments.  When I send them up to Heroku the OmniAuth stuff doesn't work.

Rails 3.1.3
Ruby 1.9.2-p290
OmniAuth 0.2.6

```
Started GET "/auth/?provider=google&return_site_id=2&return_session_id=54fb72dc1e6d29308fc6b6ec2b721889" for 76.x.x.x at 2011-12-12 20:17:33 -0800
cache: [GET /auth/?provider=google&return_site_id=2&return_session_id=54fb72dc1e6d29308fc6b6ec2b721889] miss
2011-12-13T04:17:33+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mysite.org/auth/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=104

Started GET "/auth/google" for 76.x.x.x at 2011-12-12 20:17:33 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/auth/google"):

cache: [GET /auth/google] miss
```

Comment: Whats in your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem (but am using OmniAuth 1.0). The problem is caused by the cache store not being set up on heroku.

To fix it add Memcache. Follow the [heroku docs on adding Memcache](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache) and add `config.cache_store = :dalli_store` in `config/environments/production.rb` to fix your problem.